# Apache - htdocs and /var/www/html

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services

I developed a small web application in XAMPP where APACHE had root folder - htdocs. I am trying to run the application in AMAZON was instance and there I am finding /var/www/html as the root folder.

Why does Apache has two different mechanism? OR did i get this wrong completely. Is there anything that needs to be doing to ensure the difference is taken care off.

Whats more interesting is that after deploying to AWS, none of the php files are not rendering instead its a blank white page. Really not able to figure out what is going on here.. could you please help.

Comment: Can't help without seeing the relevant code. Also, throw this to the top of your php script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. I assume it's a "500 Internal Server" error.

Answer (score 5):

> Why does Apache has two different mechanism?

It's not two different mechanisms, Apache can just be pointed at any folder you like. Your site could be hosted from `/i/accidentally/pooped/my/pants` if you felt so inclined (using the `DocumentRoot` in the config).

Some people call the web root folder `htdocs`, some say `www`, some say `public`, some say `public_html`, etc. - it varies from distribution to distribution and administrator to administrator.

A blank page with PHP usually indicates an error, which you should check `/var/logs` for (typically something like `/var/logs/apache2/error.log` or something similar).

Comment: It wasn't an accident.

Answer (score 0):

The xampp is packaged with apache, php, mysql and what you installed on amazon ec2 as each part separately. The difference only lies in document root.

If you check httpd-xampp.conf file you can find different DocumentRoot as /opt/lampp/htdocs

and incase of Amazon EC2 you can find in httpd.conf file the document root path as /var/www/html